Using pd.asfreq() on an index with duplicate values
I have a pandas timeseries with an index 'date' which has lots of duplicate dates. Now, I don't want to drop the duplicates as they refer to unique rows of data. As my data is published every week, I'd like to interpolate available data on a daily basis through forward fill.
Here's an example dataframe:
           Product        ticker        lots                
date
2012-01-05    M         XYDZ Index      1000  
2012-01-05    M         XDZY Index      2000       
2012-01-05    M         DZXY Index      3000     
2012-01-05    M         YXZD Index      4000      
2012-01-05    M         ZDXY Index      5000   
2012-01-12    M         XYDZ Index      1150  
2012-01-12    M         XDZY Index      2250       
2012-01-12    M         DZXY Index      3350     
2012-01-12    M         YXZD Index      4450      
2012-01-12    M         ZDXY Index      5550 

What I'd like to do is get this:
           Product        ticker        lots                
date
2012-01-05    M         XYDZ Index      1000  
2012-01-05    M         XDZY Index      2000       
2012-01-05    M         DZXY Index      3000     
2012-01-05    M         YXZD Index      4000      
2012-01-05    M         ZDXY Index      5000   
2012-01-06    M         XYDZ Index      1000  
2012-01-06    M         XDZY Index      2000       
2012-01-06    M         DZXY Index      3000     
2012-01-06    M         YXZD Index      4000      
2012-01-06    M         ZDXY Index      5000   ...

and so on until the 12th, where it'd repeat the same until next available data.

Not sure of the exact expected logic, but if you have groups you could perform this within groupby:
out = (df.groupby(['Product', 'ticker'], as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D').ffill()).droplevel(0)
       )

Output:
          Product      ticker    lots
date                                  
2012-01-05       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-06       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-07       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-08       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-09       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-10       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-11       M  DZXY Index  3000.0
2012-01-12       M  DZXY Index  3350.0
2012-01-05       M  XDZY Index  2000.0
2012-01-06       M  XDZY Index  2000.0
2012-01-07       M  XDZY Index  2000.0
2012-01-08       M  XDZY Index  2000.0
2012-01-09       M  XDZY Index  2000.0
2012-01-10       M  XDZY Index  2000.0
2012-01-11       M  XDZY Index  2000.0


Does a resample fit in here?

IIUC, you can use this approach to mimic a forward fill:
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["m_date"] = df["date"]

date_range = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range(start=df["date"].min(), end=df["date"].max(), freq="D"),
    columns=["date"],
)

date_range = pd.merge_asof(date_range, df[["date", "m_date"]])

df = date_range.merge(df.drop(columns="date"), how="left", on="m_date").drop(
    columns="m_date"
)

         date Product      ticker  lots
0  2012-01-05       M  XYDZ Index  1000
1  2012-01-05       M  XDZY Index  2000
2  2012-01-05       M  DZXY Index  3000
3  2012-01-05       M  YXZD Index  4000
4  2012-01-05       M  ZDXY Index  5000
5  2012-01-06       M  XYDZ Index  1000
6  2012-01-06       M  XDZY Index  2000
7  2012-01-06       M  DZXY Index  3000
8  2012-01-06       M  YXZD Index  4000
9  2012-01-06       M  ZDXY Index  5000
10 2012-01-07       M  XYDZ Index  1000
11 2012-01-07       M  XDZY Index  2000
12 2012-01-07       M  DZXY Index  3000
13 2012-01-07       M  YXZD Index  4000
14 2012-01-07       M  ZDXY Index  5000
15 2012-01-08       M  XYDZ Index  1000
16 2012-01-08       M  XDZY Index  2000
17 2012-01-08       M  DZXY Index  3000
18 2012-01-08       M  YXZD Index  4000
19 2012-01-08       M  ZDXY Index  5000
20 2012-01-09       M  XYDZ Index  1000
21 2012-01-09       M  XDZY Index  2000
22 2012-01-09       M  DZXY Index  3000
23 2012-01-09       M  YXZD Index  4000
24 2012-01-09       M  ZDXY Index  5000
25 2012-01-10       M  XYDZ Index  1000
26 2012-01-10       M  XDZY Index  2000
27 2012-01-10       M  DZXY Index  3000
28 2012-01-10       M  YXZD Index  4000
29 2012-01-10       M  ZDXY Index  5000
30 2012-01-11       M  XYDZ Index  1000
31 2012-01-11       M  XDZY Index  2000
32 2012-01-11       M  DZXY Index  3000
33 2012-01-11       M  YXZD Index  4000
34 2012-01-11       M  ZDXY Index  5000
35 2012-01-12       M  XYDZ Index  1150
36 2012-01-12       M  XDZY Index  2250
37 2012-01-12       M  DZXY Index  3350
38 2012-01-12       M  YXZD Index  4450
39 2012-01-12       M  ZDXY Index  5550

